# Partition limited and greyed out

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, catalina, partition, unix

I'm trying to partition my hard drive in order to install Ubuntu.
I'm using MacOS Catalina.
Upon selecting the device and clicking partition, I encounter that most of my hard drive space is greyed out with only 45GB to use out of 1TB. I certainly am not using most of it either. Please see image details below:

[image]

[image]

How can I get over this and use more space for the partition? Appreciate any advice.

Here's an additional image when I try to partition during the recovery mode but it doesn't allow me to resize it:

[image]

Comment: How are you booting the Mac to re-partition? The easiest way is to boot into recovery mode (Command-R at startup) and use disk utility there. Also what happens when you click the "+" button. And your partition is not so much grayed out as shown as unused with 915GB available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After clicking `+` button, the blue and grey colors appear inthe circle image. When I try to rotate to enlarge the blue area it's not allowing me to do so. I've used Disk Utility in the OS but haven't tried during recovery mode. I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: I added an image from trying the partition in recovery mode. It says the `volume can't be resized.` Appreciate any ideas.